# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/home/.../run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid

Tags: nginx

The site seems to working fine. Two days ago I activated the ssl , purchased at a CA

today, sentry came up with this error. I have looked around, but in my case, it doesn't tell me what address I should add

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not vali...
ID: b32890e16755424883af3226f307287c
Feb. 1, 2024, 12:47:51 p.m. UTC
project 500-error
environment production
level   error
Exception
DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
  File "django/http/request.py", line 167, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Request
URL https://home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock:
```

I can see this is a common error but each one's cause seems to be different. In my case, my nginx contains

```
location / {           
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;             
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;            
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

in my settings file I have:
myweb.com [www.myweb.com](http://www.myweb.com) and its IP as "allowed hosts"

SENTRY TELLS ME:

```
msg += " You may need to add %r to ALLOWED_HOSTS." % domain
        else:
            msg += (
                " The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035."
            )
        raise DisallowedHost(msg)
def get_port(self):
    """Return the port number for the request as a string."""
    if settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT and "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT" in self.META:
        port = self.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"]
```